# How to avoid headers passed back to API Gateway from Lambda via Serverless framework being remapped?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm hitting an issue when I try to respond in a [Serverless](https://serverless.com) Lambda function with the `WWW-Authenticate` challenge header.

I am setting in my response

```
{
    statusCode: 401,
    headers: {
        'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="My realm"',
    },
    body: "",
}
```

The function runs successfully but in the response I don't have a `WWW-Authenticate` header; instead, I have an `x-amzn-Remapped-WWW-Authenticate` header.

How can I have this header passed through verbatim?

I read [the docs about passing custom response headers](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#custom-response-templates), but it seems that these need to be set in `serverless.yml`. Since these response headers need to be dynamic based on the request headers I don't think that will help me.

The function is the default `lambda-proxy` type.

Comment: Would someone care to tell me why this is being downvoted?

Comment: Maybe the issue was that you don't need to know *why* I want to do this? I have removed it. Maybe that's better.

Comment: I have since found some [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html) which say this header (among others) is remapped, but it does not explain why or if there's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

By default The Serverless Framework uses the Lambda Proxy Integration method. This does lots of the heavy lifting for you, but also gets in the way.

If you want a more transparent experience you need to use Lambda Integration, and handle the response yourself. Though you'll need to get more hands on, including CORS response headers.

`integration: lambda`

You can read more about the two methods here: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#lambda-integration

Comment: I see from your latest comment, this header is handled in a unique way https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html

Comment: In light of that, is it still possible with the "lambda" integration?